# PowerShell: How to compare 2 CSVs and export desired results to a new CSV?

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to write a script that will help me parse large amounts of user session statistics. I have 2 CSVs:

currentmonth.csv

```
UserName;Hours
User1;0,5
User2;120
User3;1
```

... and ...

previousmonth.csv

```
UserName;Hours
User1;2
User2;100
```

I want to compare **currentmonth.csv** against **previousmonth.csv** and if an user (ex. **User3**) is **not** present in CSV for the previous month, give value for hours as "**0**" and save the processed data in a new CSV (ex. *parsedmonth.csv*).

Desired output:

```
UserName;Hours
User1;0,5
User2;120
User3;0
```

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
# Load the 2 CSV files
$currentmonth = import-csv .\currentmonth.csv -delimiter ';'
$previousmonth = import-csv .\previousmonth.csv -delimiter ';'

# Variable to hold output
$op = @()

foreach($entry in $currentmonth)
{
    # Loop through all entries in the current month and check against previous month
    if($previousmonth.username -contains $entry.username)
    {
        # If found, add the entry to the output variable
        $op += $entry
    }
    else
    {
        # If not found, create a temp object to hold values and add to output variable
        $tmp = new-object object
        $tmp | add-member -type noteproperty -name UserName $entry.UserName
        $tmp | add-member -type noteproperty -name Hours 0
        $op += $tmp
    }
}

# Write output variable to CSV file
$op | export-csv .\monthcheckresults.csv -notype
```

Comment: Thank you, this produces the result I wanted!